# Predecessor function with recursive types

Tags: functional-programming, haskell, mu-recursion, agda

I am defining the type `Nat` of natural numbers a recursive sum type:

$$ Nat = \mu X. Unit \oplus X$$

Now, I have defined `zero` as the term:

```
zero : Nat
zero = fold Nat (Inl tmUnit tyNat tyUnit)
```

and successor as

```
succ : Nat -> Nat
succ n = fold Nat (tmInr n tyNat tyUnit)
```

Please note, that I am not completely sure of these two implementations; they might be wrong - I accept comments on them too.

Now, my question: I want to implement a predecessor function. I have both an `isZero` function and an `if-then-else` construct. How could I to this?

Comment: I'll assume you're trying to study type encodings. Could you please show a more complete source of what you have so far? For example, your definitions of `Nat`, and `isZero`.

Comment: I am not well versed with Agda, but will copying church encoding for predecessor help in your case? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Table_of_functions_on_Church_numerals